# Write free hand on MacBook pro

Tags: osx

I am a math teacher and I want to record my lessons which contain free handwriting for math symbols and so on.

Would you please to help me by telling the best tool & program to do this.

Comment: Wouldn't a program like paint work? What would make a program the "best"? Can you add more information to what exactly you're looking for? This would help pull better answers, thank you.

Comment: OS X used to have 'Ink' - a handwriting recognition app - built in... unfortunately no longer :/